# Configure CPU Scrypt miner

Tags: miner-configuration, scrypt, cpu

I've decided to give 42coin a shot with CPU mining but the CPU miner that I've found doesn't specify how to configure it. It DOES give you the parameters though. I'm not sure if I should add a .bat file or a .conf or their's some kind of other way of configuring it.

Miner is here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=55038.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a txt file and name it 42mine.bat in your pooler cpu directory (make sure when you save the file, click all files and then save)
copy this into your bat file
minerd --url=stratum+tcp://42.coinpool.de:1042 --userpass=my.Worker:Password

Replacing my.Worker with your workers name and Password with your Password

Then save the bat file, again make sure it is with the all files option.

You can actually do this with all scrypt coins, saving each bat file under the specific coin.